# onelogin - get admin privileges via api

Tags: onelogin

We're building a small integration with onelogin to just pull out lists of users and which apps they have. Easy enough via the API.

But we are also wanting to get a list of the administrative privileges like super user, manage accounts, and so on. The docs don't mention those. Is there any way to pull out those details via the API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time you can't do that. You are limited to roles and groups.